# Video Capture Not working With UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I call a function when a button is pressed to present the imagePickerController but it seems that when a video must be taken the app crashes, even when I am running on a device (iPad 2).

```
@IBAction func beginTest() {
    imagePicker =  UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeVideo as String, kUTTypeImage as String]
    if photoTests.contains(currentTestNum) {
        imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .Photo
    } else {
        imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .Video //exception thrown here.
    }
    presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: You should use `UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(.Camera)` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImagePickerController/availableMediaTypesForSourceType:

Comment: You should use kUTTypeMovie, not video. Some iOS devices support video recording. Use this method, along with the isSourceTypeAvailable: method, to determine if video recording is available on a device. The availability of video recording is indicated by the presence of the kUTTypeMovie media type for the UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera source type.